# regex for returning first sentence from a bigger text Python3

Tags: python, regex

I want to get the first sentence from a text. I am encountering various text formats.
Using Python3 *re.split()*
.the regex I wrote: `'.*\. [A-Z]'` meaning take anything until format appears.
This works form 90% of the cases, the case with 'Dr. Firstname Lastname' in the first sentence is breaking the pattern, it gets the first sentence until Firstname.
I was thinking of trying to exclude substrings like 'Dr. [A-Z]' but cannot figure out a way to do it.
Any ideas? Thanks
Sample:***The rain in U.S.A. and Spain is researched by Dr. Martin Laurance. This is the latest U.S.A. study. Anything else will just be ignored.***

Comment: Please add some real input strings and tag the programming language in question. Additionally, you might be looking for language processing tools (e.g. `nltk` for `Python`) rather than regular expressions alone. You're likely to encounter problems that have already been solved using machine leaning algorithms (e.g. `Prof. Dr.`, `U.S.A.`, etc.).

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_regex_split

did not write any of the details because it really doesn't matter if it's python or anything else, it works the same.

Comment: 'This is the U.S.A.' vs 'This is the U.S.A. study.' Shows that you won't do it with only regex if you don't mark the end of the sentence otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel, the problem has been tackled before.
When using `Python` (what your link suggests), give [**`nltk`**](https://www.nltk.org/) a try:

```
from nltk import sent_tokenize

string = "The rain in U.S.A. and Spain is researched by Dr. Martin Laurance. This is the latest U.S.A. study. Anything else will just be ignored."
for sent in sent_tokenize(string):
    print(sent)
```

This yields

```
The rain in U.S.A. and Spain is researched by Dr. Martin Laurance.
This is the latest U.S.A. study.
Anything else will just be ignored.
```

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to kill a minute or two (or 25  ;)) so I came up with this (not at all foolproof) solution:

```
(?i).*?\b((?=[a-z']*[aoueiy])(?=[a-z']*[^aoueiy])\w{2,}\.)
```

What it does is to identify a word followed by a full stop. To separate this word from any abbreviations it's searching for a sequence of characters ( `{2,}` = more than 1) than contains at least one vowel and one consonant. This is achieved using two "look a heads" prior to matching the word.

Look a head to find a vowel in a word: `(?=[a-z]*[aoueiy])`

`[a-z]*` = any number of letters followed by the character class `[aoueiy]` - a vowel.

The consonant is the same, only with a negated character class `[^aoueiy]` matching any consonant (and also any other non letter, but since the match is letters only it doesn't matter ;)

Note that this is of course is nothing close to a complete language parser, but it may work in many cases. One thing it would miss is sentences end with the one letter word "I". Like "We're good together you and I."

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sciFcK/4)

Comment: I just spend a minute to break it. "This sentence will not be captured, because it uses a kommata." ;-)

Comment: @Darkproduct Was fixing that while you commented ;) Didn't handle apostrophes either.